# Matlab neural network testing

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have created a neural network and the performance is good. By using nprtool, we are allow to test the network with an input data and target data. Here is my question, what is the purpose of testing a neural network with target data provided? Isn't it testing should not hav e target data so that we can know how well can the trained neural network perform without target data is given? Hope someone will respond to this, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `nprtool`, but I suspect it would give the *input* data to your neural network, and then compare your NN's *output* data with the *target* data (and compute some kind of success rate based on that).

**So your NN will never see the *target* data, it's just used to measure the performance.**

It's like the "teacher's edition" of the exercise books in school. The student (i.e. the NN) doesn't have the solutions, but her/his answers will be compared against them by the teacher (i.e. `nprtool`). (Okay, the teacher probably/hopefully knows the subject, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

The "target" data `t` is the desired `y` of `y=net(x)` used as example to train the network.
What nprtool do is to divide the training set into three groups: the training set, the validation set and the test set.

The first one is used to actually update the network.

The second one is used to determine the performances of the net (note: this set is NOT used in any way to update the network): as the NN "learns" the error (as difference between the `t` and `net(x)`) over the validation set decreases. The trend will eventually stop or even reverse: this phenomena is called "[overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)", which means the NN is now chasing the training set, "memorizing" it at the cost of the ability to generalize (meaning: to perform well with unseen data). So the purpose of this validation set is to determine when to stop the training before the NN starts overfitting. This should answer your question.

Finally third set is for external testing, to leave you a set of data untouched by the training procedure.

Comment: To clarify:

The validation set is generally used to compare the different architectures or parameters of the neural network. For example, while the training set is used to train the network, the validation set would be used to determine how many layers/nodes to have. It can also be used to find a good regularisation parameter.

The reason the test set can't be used for this is because the architecture can overfit the validation set, in the same way the learning algorithm can overfit the training set.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the total data set [training, validation and testing] are inputs to the training algorithm, the testing data is in no way used to design (i.e., train and validate) the net

total  = design + test

design = train + validate

The training data is used to estimate weights and biases

The validation data is used to monitor the design performance on nontraining data. REGARDLESS OF THE PERFORMANCE ON TRAINING DATA, if validation performance degrades continuously for 6 (default) epochs, training is terminated (VALIDATION STOPPING).

This mitigates the dreaded phenomenon of OVERTRAINING AN OVERFIT NET where performance on nontraining data degrades even if the training set performance is improving.

An overfit net has more unknown weights and biases than training equations, thereby allowing an infinite number of solutions. A simple example of overfitting with two unknowns but only one equation:

KNOWN: a, b, c

FIND:  unique x1 and x2

USING:                       a * x1 + b * x2 = c

Hope this helps.

Greg